# Setting a legend name to anonymous geom_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to set a legend name for an anonymous geom_function?

I manage to get a legend for the different species of Iris, but would like to give a label for my line as well.

Many thanks!

```
data("iris")

iris %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape=Species))+
geom_point()+
geom_function(fun=~.x^(1/2))
```

Comment: Could you provide a rough sketch of what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the same as always if you need a legend in ggplot2: Create an aesthetic mapping.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_function(fun=~.x^(1/2), aes(linetype = "function")) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "some")
```